# Не открываются окна TK

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
btn = Button(tk, text="Клацни мене")
btn.pack()
```

Answer (score 2):

В конце нужно добавить

```
tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
btn = Button(tk, text="Клацни мене")
btn.pack()
mainloop()
```